# Execute Javascript code when a file upload completes without requiring page refresh

Tags: php, html

I have created a file-upload form and I want to output "filetransfer succeeded" in a `<div>` when the file transfer is done.

This is easilly done on a normal form using Jquery and Ajax but since this is a file upload it is not possible to use ajax.

So how do I upload a file and give feedback back to the user?

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking at [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) or [swfupload](http://www.swfupload.org/).

I have personally used uploadify and you can do:

```
 $('input[type=file]').MultiFile({ 
  list: '#DIV to update'
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery actually has a pretty slick plugin called [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) that'll let you do this. Alternately the iFrame solution Emil suggested will work as well without any outside libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in an iframe.